# gapi.client.load() results 404 Error for google calendar v3

Tags: javascript, calendar

**code -**

```
var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
        'calendarId': 'primary',
        'resource': event
    });

request.execute(function(event) {
  console.log('Event created: ' + event.htmlLink);
});
```

and it gives the url as follow

https://content.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json&key=AIzaSyAqWDNNcpsJNNaZO5Bq8tmiSzvzR1YArAo

I couldn't find the reason. is it something problem in my api key or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! i am very sorry i have found the solution of this problem. Actually the event object that i was sending to calendar was wrong. Now its working fine.it was a silly mistake of mine.This is my total code and it is working fine for me.......

```
var CLIENT_ID = 'myClientId';
var SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"];
var EvntJSn = '';

function addEventInGoogle(eventList){
    EvntJSn = eventList;
    var apiKey = 'myapikey';
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);

    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
        'immediate': true
      }, handleAuthResult);
}

/**
* Handle response from authorization server.
*
* @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
*/

function handleAuthResult(authResult){
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      loadCalendarApi();
    } else {
     handleAuthClick(event);
    }
}

/**
* Initiate auth flow in response to user clicking authorize button.
*
* @param {Event} event Button click event.
*/

function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
    {
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        immediate: false
    },
    handleAuthResult);
    return false;
}

function loadCalendarApi() {
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', addEventToGglCalendar);
}

function addEventToGglCalendar(){
    var event = EvntJSn;
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
        'calendarId': 'primary',
        'resource': event
    });

    request.execute(function(event) {
      console.log(event);
    });
}
```